# CI/CD free for hobby side projects. Jenkins on Heroku as alternative, with ephemeral dyno

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, travis-ci

I have four side projects which are my hobby (NOT A JOB! NOT A WORK!).

I work on that at night, when I have time and when I want to.

All projects are javascript backend and frontend. Just experiments.

What I need is a Jenkins instance (or something like that for CI (continuous integration) and maybe also CD (continuous delivery)) but **free**. Maybe like free heroku dyno which is amazing: I don't work everyday on it, I work sometimes, when I have time and, like my free dyno on Heroku it's amazing the auto-sleep and go on just when I need it.

Is there something for Jenkins out there but free, with auto-sleep?

**Jenkins on Heroku** is still an option given the ephemeral state of dyno on Heroku? Is Jenkins still saving config on filesystem?

I can't afford to pay something for that because it's just an experiment.

Any idea?

Comment: Sign up for openshift online. They have a free tier.
sign up for AWS free tier.

Answer (score 1):

You should try CI / CD like:

- [Codeship](https://codeship.com/) ( free tier, and totally free for open source projects )
- [travisci](https://travis-ci.org/)
- [circleci](https://circleci.com/), ...

Openshift, as @JamesKnott mention, but this one is a full PaaS, so it is meant to host your app too.

Hope it helps